# USB Y Cable - Does it only split the power or also the data?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Does an USB-Y-Cable (often found for USB 3.0 devices, for better backwards compatibility/faster speed?) like the following just splits the power or also the data? The second USB-male-plug has a thinner cable, so I think something is missing there.

[image]

I didn't find an answer on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power only. There is no way for two devices to signal serially without a hub. It is however possible to have a very small hub. So, unless your "y" splitter is also a two port hub; It's power only.